# Ползамка красивого / пол замка красивого

Tags: орфография

У Лопатина написано – здесь: [http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=80#pp80написано](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=80#pp80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE), – что если приставка прибавляется к словосочетанию, то тогда она вообще раздельно пишется (если, конечно, это не словосочетание, через дефис написанное). В связи с этим я имею такой вопрос: правда ли, что во всех следующих случаях надо именно так писать?

1. Я увидел ползамка красивого.
2. Свинья съела полжёлудя дерева.
3. У меня было полдочери, по-французски говорящей.
4. У меня есть пол-унитаза сломанного.
5. У меня есть полкота, себя вылизывающего.